# Git::Repository wont run git log

Tags: git, perl

I've tried running `git log --since 2013-09-17` via `Git::Repository-run`, but it's not working. It states that

```
git: 'log --since=2013-09-17' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

However when I run the command on the console, it works pretty well. Here's my code:

```
 41 my $repo = Git::Repository->new(
 42         git_dir => $git_path,
 43 );
 44 my $log_cmd = 'log'.($from ? " --since=$from" : '').($to ? " --until=$to" : '');
 48 my @commits = $repo->run($log_cmd);
```

Also note that `log` without any since/until-params is running just fine.

Does any of you guys have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parameter *list* as arguments to `run()` here, similar like you would use the list form of perl's `system()` or `exec()` builtins:

```
my @log_cmd = ('log', ($from ? "--since=$from" : ()), ($to ? "--until=$to" : ()));
my @commits = $repo->run(@log_cmd);
```

Comment: Hah, i should've put a bit more attention into reading the docs. Thanks, mate! Though the code you provided won't work, because it won't accept `''` as a parameter. But building the cmd as an array works.